# How can I run a mutt macro at startup (from command line)?

Tags: mutt

As an example: `mutt -e '<limit>all\\n'`, causes:

```
Error in command line: <limit>all\n: unknown command
Press any key to continue...
```

**How can I have mutt interpret that correctly?**

*(I've also tried variants like `mutt -e 'macro index "<limit>all\\n"'`.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two changes to your command to get it to work:

1. use [mutt's `push` command](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#push) to execute functions
2. use `<enter>` rather than `\\n` to trigger the enter key at the end of the command

Thus, this is the command needed:

```
mutt -e "push '<limit>all<enter>'"
```

Useful reference: [Mutt's function listing](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#functions) for macros.

Comment: May this be combined with variables defined in muttrc? I am trying to do `mutt -e "push '$my_limit_cmd'"` in order to start out with a custom filter.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're setting `$my_limit_cmd` to?

Comment: `set my_limit_cmd="<limit>all<enter>"` for example,